# 1.Variable no definida $descuento

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

1.Variable no definida $descuento. Quiero poner `{{$discount->discount_id}}` en la vista de ofertas, pero no lo define, en la base de datos tengo la tabla de descuentos con discount_id.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Models\Photo;
    use App\Models\Discount;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class HomeController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('auth');
        }

        /**
         * Show the application dashboard.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
         */
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $photos = Photo::all();
            $discounts = Discount::where('discount_id', '=', $request->discountId);

            return view('offers', ['photos' => $photos, 'discounts' => $discounts, 'result' => null]);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

[image: HomeController]

2 En la vista de ofertas quiero poner `{{$discount->discount_id}}` para que se vea desde la base de datos pero me pone

> Undefined variable $discount        ( offers.blade.php)

```
{{$discount->discount_id}}
<div class="card-body">
<!-- <h5>{{$photo->description}} </h5> -->
@if ($result && $photo->id == $result->product_id)
```

Comment: La variable del controlador se llama discounts, no? En la vista, estas usando discount. Sin la 's' del final.

Comment: @D.Albarracín gracias, aunque no es el error ya lo he comprobado varias veces, creo que con laravel tiene que ser singular, aunque le ponga la "s" no funciona.

Comment: Después del where(), añade un '->get()' en el controlador

Comment: La variable que le pasas a la vista, se llama `$discounts`, da igual como se llame la tabla en Laravel, ya que tu le pones el nombre que quieres cuando se lo pasas a la vista. Por otro lado, como bien dice @D.Albarracín , tienes que poner `->get()` para que te lo devuelva como objeto de tu Modelo

Comment: @D.Albarracín   $discounts = Discount::where ('discount_id', '=', $request->discountId)->get()
            ->where('discount_id', '=', $request->code)->get();   asi?

Comment: $discounts = Discount::where ('discount_id', '=', $request->discountId)->get();

Comment: @D.Albarracín     Da este error:                                                                                Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\Users\user\Documents\offer-app\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php on line 31 and at least 1 expected

Comment: @D.Albarracín  He quitado lo siguiente     ->where('discount_id', '=', $request->code)->get(); pero sigue con el error

Comment: Asegurate de que no hay ningún espacio en blanco donde no debería, ya que en lo que te ha proporcionado @D.Albarracín tiene un espacio en blanco

Comment: @Maidagan  esto es lo que tengo  $discounts = Discount::where ('discount_id', '=', $request->discountId)->get();
         
          
        $discount = $discounts->first();

Comment: Si usas `get()` debes pasar al menos un parámetro, que sería el nombre de la columna que quieres retornar. Si quieres sólo el primer elemento de esa colección puedes usar `first()`, y si los quieres todos usa `all()`, en ambos casos sin usar `get()`.

Comment: en todo caso la consulta a la base de datos seria: `$discounts = Discount::where('discount_id', '=', $request->discountId)->get('discount_id');` o si quieres el primer registro : `$discounts = Discount::where('discount_id', '=', $request->discountId)->first();`